# Unity - How to stop an moving UI component in the canvas?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, canvas

I have six panels which shows the current effect of the player. They should only appear if the player has an active effect (already coded that). I want to give the panels some aesthetics, they should appear really fast from the left side and should stop moving when they entered the canvas compeltely (not really completely, some of the left side should stay outside so it looks a little bit better). I coded the movement already, but I don't know how to stop the panels from moving.

```
//The effect bar system gets activated
effectbar.SetActive(true);

//The movement vector
Vector3 movePanel = new Vector3(100, 0, 0);

for (int i = 0; i < effectCount; i++)
{
    effectbar.gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.SetActive(true);
    effectbar.gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).transform.Translate(movePanel * Time.deltaTime * 3f);
    activeCount++;
}
```

Should I make an empty UI component and use it like a wall, or use a timer and stop it after an defined amount of time, or is there a better way? Thanks forwards.
[image: Panels should move until they completed entering the screen (a bit of the left side should stay outside)]

Comment: When do you start to move the UI? When do you stop? I mean, what happens to cause these two? It's really important to mention this in order to get a proper answer.

Comment: I recommend a [tween engine](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/search/page=1/sortby=relevance/query=tween&price:0).  [DoTween](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/27676) is one I've used before and its pretty good.

Comment: @Draco18s My purpose on making games is to learn coding, I am voluntary learning the complicated stuff.

Comment: An admirable goal, for sure. But there are times when you shouldn't reinvent the wheel. Tweening is one of them. Writing code to move "these five objects into place on condition Y" will only ever move those five objects. You want to do "the exact same thing to those six items over there, also slower, and they should bounce" and you have to write it all over again. A tweening engine says, "Look, just tell me what you want me to do and to what" and leaves you free from having to micromanage your UI.

Comment: Maybe I can look for such things later. But for now I am just doing the prototyping. Aesthetic comes on end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Vector3.Lerp(start, end, time)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) function.

Here is an example class:

```
public class MoveObjectTowards : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform TargetTransform;
    public float Speed;

    private void Update ()
    {
        if (!IsAtTarget())
        {
            MoveTowardsTarget();
        }
    }

    private void MoveTowardsTarget()
    {
        gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(gameObject.transform.position, TargetTransform.position,
            Speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private bool IsAtTarget()
    {
        return gameObject.transform.position == TargetTransform.position;
    }
}
```

You should attach this to your `effectBar` gameObject and set up the valeus in the inspector, after that it should work. You must also create some object that will act as a 'wall' and assign it to `public Transform TargetTransform`.

Comment: Note: You would need to do this every frame with some value for the "time" parameter beteween 0 and 1.

Comment: @Draco18s that's a good point but I assume OP's code is executed in the Update function already, else it wouldn't continue moving.

Comment: I know you know. I've just seen people go "oh, I put a 1 here because I want it to move all the way." Or "I'll put `Time.time` here because I want it to happen over time." Stuff like that.

Answer (score 0):

So I have coded following:

```
float startTime = Time.time;
float speed = 1f;
float distanceDone = (Time.time - startTime) * speed;
Vector3 panelStart = new Vector3(effectbar.gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.transform.position.x, effectbar.gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.transform.position.y);
Vector3 panelMovement = new Vector3(effectbar.gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.transform.position.x+140,effectbar.gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.transform.position.y);
Vector3 panelStop = new Vector3(panelMovement.x, 
effectbar.gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.transform.position.y);
effectbar.gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(panelStart, panelStop, distanceDone / Vector3.Distance(panelStart,panelMovement));
```

And ingame following happens: The panel doesn't move. Did I code something wrong?

Edit: I guess that happened because I didn't use `Transform` instead of `Vector3`, right?

Comment: Via a method, yes.

Comment: You should have only the logic/code that moves the object inside the Update method, the rest you should do only **once**.

Comment: Fixed that, but now the box flies away.

Comment: @Deadzone Nope, I didn't fix everything. Now it works. Thank you for your help again!

Comment: I just added an example class in my answer @Echi, anyway I'm glad you figured it out, good job!